# How to find the differences between two tables that were once identically but one is now corrupt

Tags: mysql, select, datatable

I have a table (Table A) which I have created an identically copy of (Table B). After the copy is made, Table A has become corrupt (or in other words, some rows have been deleted or added, and some rows have had data changed). I want to create a single select statement that lists all the rows that have been deleted, modified and inserted into Table A. I have looked at other peoples problems which are similar but I feel they are not the same as what I am asking. Im imagining a statement along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE TABLE_ID NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_ID FROM TABLE_B);
```

This however does not do exactly what I want as I want to find changes in every column, not just TABLE_ID.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Find rows in TABLE_A that don't have a matching row in *all* columns of TABLE_B:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.TABLE_ID
FROM TABLE_A LEFT NATURAL JOIN TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_B.TABLE_ID IS NULL
```

Find the reverse: rows in TABLE_B that don't have a matching row in *all* columns of TABLE_A:

```
SELECT TABLE_B.TABLE_ID
FROM TABLE_B LEFT NATURAL JOIN TABLE_A
WHERE TABLE_A.TABLE_ID IS NULL
```

That should get you started.